# Trying to understand a nested .each loop

Tags: ruby

My assignment:

> Implement a method #stock_picker that takes in an array of stock prices, one for each hypothetical day. It should return a pair of days representing the best day to buy and the best day to sell. Days start at 0.
>
> ```
> > stock_picker([17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10])
> => [1,4]  # for a profit of $15 - $3 == $12
> ```
>
> Quick Tips:
>
> - You need to buy before you can sell
> - Pay attention to edge cases like when the lowest day is the last day or the highest day is the first day.

My Code:

```
def stock_picker(array)

largest = 0
smallest = 1000
largest_index = 1
smallest_index = 0

array.each { |small| 

array.each { |large| 

if small < smallest && array.index(small) < largest_index

        smallest = small
        smallest_index = array.index(small)
    #puts 'smallest = ' + smallest.to_s

end
if large > largest && array.index(large) > smallest_index 

        largest = large
        largest_index = array.index(large)
    #puts "largest = " + largest.to_s
end


    }
}

 [smallest_index, largest_index]

end
p stock_picker([17,3,6,9,15,8,6,1,10])
p stock_picker([4,6,9,34,28,12,2,16,8,44])
p stock_picker([8, 5, 3, 6 ,8, 56, 43, 76, 54, 9])
p stock_picker([6, 2, 7, 3, 1, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9])
p stock_picker([99, 88, 77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 22, 11, 99])
```

My code works for the first 4 tests, but gets stuck on [0,1] for the last test. 
I don't understand why the nested .each won't iterate past the assigned values. If I change the last '99', it runs fine.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I give you some hints: 1) `Array.index` will only find the FIRST occurrence. If you have multiple occurrences (e.g. 99 two times), it only finds the first 99. 2) You might want to use the method `Array.each_with_index` instead of `Array.each`. This will remove the need for calling `Array.index`, which you cannot use here anyway, because it doesn't work with multiple occurrences.

Comment: Oh nice, is it on hackerrank or some other site? Can you link to it?

Comment: @Casper Thank you so much for your reply. This is exactly what I needed to know to understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The given daily prices are as follows:

```
prices = [17, 3, 6, 9, 15, 8, 6, 1, 10]
```

The price is `17` on day `0`, `3` on day `1`, and so on. I assume a stock can be bought and sold on the same day.

The first step is determine, for each possible “buy” day `i`, `0 <= i <= prices.size-1`, the “sell” day `j`, `i <= j <= prices.size-1` for which the price is highest, and save the information needed to an array of hashes, one hash for each possible “buy” day:

```
returns = prices.each_index.map do |i|
  j = (i..prices.size-1).max_by { |j| prices[j] }
  { buy_day: i, sell_day: j, return: prices[j]-prices[i] }
end
  #=> [{:buy_day=>0, :sell_day=>0, :return=>0},
  #    {:buy_day=>1, :sell_day=>4, :return=>12},
  #    {:buy_day=>2, :sell_day=>4, :return=>9},
  #    {:buy_day=>3, :sell_day=>4, :return=>6},
  #    {:buy_day=>4, :sell_day=>4, :return=>0},
  #    {:buy_day=>5, :sell_day=>8, :return=>2},
  #    {:buy_day=>6, :sell_day=>8, :return=>4},
  #    {:buy_day=>7, :sell_day=>8, :return=>9},
  #    {:buy_day=>8, :sell_day=>8, :return=>0}]
```

This tells us that if we buy on day `0` (at `17`), we should sell right away, yielding a net return of zero. If we buy on day `1` (at `3`) we should sell on day `4` (at `15`), yielding a net return of `15 - 3 = 12`. If we buy at day`7` we should sell on day `8` yielding a return of `9`.

It remains to determine the maximum value of `return`:

```
h = returns.max_by { |h| h[:return] }
  #=> {:buy_day=>1, :sell_day=>4, :return=>12}
```

This provides all the information we need: buy on day `h[:buy_day] #=> 1`, sell on day `h[:sell_day] #=> 4`, and achieve a return of `h[:return] #=> 12`.

See [Array#each_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-each_index) and [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by).

Comment: I have not identified the problem with the OP's code in my answer as @Casper has done that in a comment on the question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is good to know, but as you said above, Casper has pointed out my error.